# Ubuntu 20.04 ownCloud error

Tags: 20.04, mysql, mariadb, owncloud-server, owncloud-client

I'm having some issues with a fresh installation of ownCloud on my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop.

This is what i get after trying to login:

[image]

Comment: 'Server is gone away' (not for lunch, course) can result from a timeout between the establishment of the connection and the first SQL activity.  I would restart ownCloud to see if the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to the problem myself:

```
cd /path/to/your/owncloud
wget https://gist.github.com/VicDeo/bb0689104baeb5ad2371d3fdb1a013ac/raw/04bb98e08719a04322ea883bcce7c3e778e3afe1/DoctrineMariaDB102.patch
patch -p0 < DoctrineMariaDB102.patch
```

Source: https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/28695#issuecomment-332174798